# out of memory exception in server filtering kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-grid

i want to show large data in kendo grid using skip and take solution for server paging and filtering. my controller and method is :

```
public ActionResult LoadStudents(int page, int pageSize, int take, bool? activeOnly)
    {
        var sorterCollection = KendoGridSorterCollection.BuildCollection(Request);
        var filterCollection = KendoGridFilterCollection.BuildCollection(Request);

        ...

        LogUI.Data.kiwiEntities en = new Data.kiwiEntities();

        var result = en.Syslogds.Where(s => el.Contains(s.MsgHostAddress)
                           && op.Contains(s.MsgCustom04.Trim()));
        var filteredStudents = result.MultipleFilter(filterCollection.Filters);
        int coun = filteredStudents.Count();
        var pagedData = filteredStudents.OrderBy(t => t.MsgDateTime).Skip((page-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        var pagedDataList = pagedData.ToList();
        var jsonData = new { total = coun, pagedDataList };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my MultipleFilter Method is :

```
public static IQueryable<T> MultipleFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> data,
      List<KendoGridFilter> filterExpressions)
    {
        if ((filterExpressions == null) || (filterExpressions.Count <= 0))
        {
            return data;
        }

        IQueryable<T> filteredquery = from item in data select item;

        for (int i = 0; i < filterExpressions.Count; i++ )
        {
            var index = i;

            Func<T, bool> expression = item =>
                {
                    var filter = filterExpressions[index];
                    var itemValue = item.GetType()
                        .GetProperty(filter.Field)
                        .GetValue(item, null);

                    if (itemValue == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var value = filter.Value;
                    switch (filter.Operator)
                    {
                        case "eq":
                            return itemValue.ToString() == value;
                        case "startswith":
                            return itemValue.ToString().StartsWith(value);
                        case "contains":
                            return itemValue.ToString().Contains(value);
                        case "endswith":
                            return itemValue.ToString().EndsWith(value);
                    }

                    return true;
                };

            filteredquery = filteredquery.Where(expression).AsQueryable();
        }
        return filteredquery;
    }
```

every things are ok but when i use filter in my kendo grid i have a out of memory exception in filteredStudents variable.

Comment: What filter are you trying to achieve?

Comment: every filter . like itemvalue.tostring() == value

Comment: Kendo should be able to do this automatically if you are using `ToDataSourceResult()` extension method. Have you tried that?

Comment: no i just tried do this with filter method because my data is very huge and custom. i don't have any idea about ToDataSourceResult() . do you  have any sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an example on [Kendo UI forum](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/ajax-binding).
Below is an example from that page so you can get an idea how the method works:

```
 public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var northwind = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            IQueryable<Product> products = northwind.Products;
            //Convert the Product entities to ProductViewModel instances.
            DataSourceResult result = products.ToDataSourceResult(request, product => new ProductViewModel
                    {
                    ProductID = product.ProductID,
                    ProductName = product.ProductName,
                    UnitsInStock = product.UnitsInStock
                    });
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```